# Where to Specify Time to Train in ML.NET

Tags: c#, ml.net, ml.net-model-builder

I'm evaluating ML.NET Model Builder (Preview) 16.1.0.2027905.  When I go to train, the Builder lets me specify "Time to train (seconds)" (See Picture):

[image]

However, when I get to Step#6 and generate the code, I can't seem to find where the "Time to train" is specified...

The ML.NET Builder creates this function for me automatically in the ModelBuilder.cs file:

```
    public static ITransformer TrainModel(MLContext mlContext, IDataView trainingDataView, IEstimator<ITransformer> trainingPipeline)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("=============== Training  model ===============");

        ITransformer model = trainingPipeline.Fit(trainingDataView);

        Console.WriteLine("=============== End of training process ===============");
        return model;
    }
```

but I looked in the debugger at the mlContext, trainingDataView, trainingPipeline objects and didn't immediately see where I can specify time to train.  Also, I did a global text search for 3600 (which is the time I trained for) and I didn't find any interesting code that way.

Is there some easy way in ML.NET to specify "Time to train" in seconds?

I'm asking this question because I want to call ModelBuilder.TrainModel manually with a user specified training interval.  I don't want to always be required to use the ML.NET Builder GUI to retrain my model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Model Builder uses AutoML behind the scenes. The code that it produces is the pure ML.NET API code so it wouldn't have a way to specify the training time.

If you want to use that, you would need to use the AutoML API. With that it has a way to specify the training time. Here's [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/how-to-use-the-automl-api#configure-experiment-settings) that shows it, but it would be something like the below code:

```
var settings = new RegressionExperimentSettings
{
    MaxExperimentTimeInSeconds = 20,
};
```

Here's a [full sample](https://github.com/jwood803/MLNetExamples/blob/master/MLNetExamples/AutoML/Program.cs) on it which was used in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zohPwDzaV6c).

Hope that helps!

Comment: The C# AutoML API works for me but for some reason when I call CreateMulticlassClassificationExperiment with a maxExperimentTimeInSeconds greater than 12 seconds (or so), the experiment takes an inordinate amount of time to finish.  For example: if I specify 10 seconds, it takes 10 seconds to finish, but if I specify 15 seconds, it might take 6 minutes to finish.  I tried two different computers and I haven't figured out why the maxExperimentTimeInSeconds parameter doesn't seem to be working for me.  Maybe a new question but I don't want to go that far just yet.